# How to test Python Code on Darwin (via virtualiziation)

Tags: python, darwin

I wrote a little tool to dump the environment of a python interpreter: [dumpenv](https://github.com/guettli/dumpenv)

I have only a linux operating system.

Is there a way to test my code on darwin os?

AFAIK running darwin in a docker container is not possible.

Buying hardware is not an option.

Comment: Are you aware of tools like [conda](https://conda.io/docs/) and/or [docker](https://www.docker.com/)?

Comment: most likely you need a hackintosh in VM, search OSX-KVM

Comment: Run tests on travis as it offers an [OSX environment](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/osx/). You already have travis build job configured, simply extend the build matrix and you're good to go.

Comment: @hoefling I would like to run the test on my linux pc. Yes, travis would be a solution, but a solution with a faster edit-test cycle is preferred.

Comment: AFAIK there's no legal way to spin up a MacOS VM without owning the hardware (correct me if I'm wrong); aside from that, I had a rather bad experience with hackintosh and patching DSDT tables to trick MacOS into thinking you have the right hardware. In the end, I went with buying a used Mac Mini and setting up the ssh access. For open source projects though, running tests via Travis is a decent alternative that saves both money and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. The MacOS license allows you to run a limited number of virtual machines, but only on Mac hardware.  I would use Parallels to run fresh copies of different MacOS systems when testing installation.  This does not allow you make a 'hackintosh' by trying to boot up MacOS on a non-Apple hardware stack.
2. Rent a system in the cloud.  As an example, [MacInCloud](https://www.macincloud.com/) will charge you about $20 per month for a system suitable for testing.
3. Rent hardware.  There is a surprisingly robust market for this.

Here is a [random recent article](https://codewithchris.com/xcode-for-windows/) on options.   Good luck!